# Использование дженериков в сочетании с интерфейсом и enum

Tags: java

Проблема в следующем: есть интерфейс с методом, который осуществляют 2 класса. Эти классы, соответственно, переопределяют данный метод, а в теле метода ссылаются на 2 различных enum (у каждого свой). Данный метод необходимо создать с возвращаемым типом одного из enum, полученного в результате работы тела метода. Но так как это два метода с различным возвращаемым типом, я решил использовать дженерики, правда пока с синтаксисом таких замен на разобрался, да и вообще, возможно ли так сделать?

Answer (score 0):

Да, такое сделать вполне возможно, фактически у вас получается интерфейс, типизированный по классу `Enum<E extends Enum<E>>`, так как в джаве все енумы [наследуются от этого класса](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Enum.html):

> *This is the common base class of all Java language enumeration types.*

Значит, ваш интерфейс должен выглядеть как:

```java
public interface Foo<T extends Enum<T>> {
    T foo();
}
```

Если требуемый интерфейс содержит только один метод, то фактически у вас получается функциональный интерфейс, и для его реализаций можно будет использовать лямбды:

```java
enum Good { GREAT, EXCELLENT,NICE }
enum Bad { POOR, WRONG, INCORRECT, INVALID }

// ...
Foo<Good> good = () -> Good.GREAT;
Foo<Bad> bad = () -> Bad.WRONG;

System.out.println(good.foo()); // -> GREAT
System.out.println(bad.foo());  // -> WRONG
```

В частности, можно было бы переиспользовать существующий функциональный интерфейс [`Supplier`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/Supplier.html), возвращающий результат нужного типа посредством метода [`Supplier::get`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/Supplier.html#get--):

```java
Supplier<Good> supplierExcellent = () -> Good.EXCELLENT;

System.out.println(supplierExcellent.get()); // -> EXCELLENT
```